# How to stream OpenGL Framebuffer?

Tags: opengl, streaming

I have been trying to find a fairly cross-compatible way to stream a framebuffer from my game to a single client. The client will be on the local network and I want to have the stream be as low latency as possible. I was thinking some form of h264 and UDP but I am not finding a good solution.

Anyone have good advice on creating a stream server as part of my game?